# Android SDK manager installation in eclipse linux

Tags: android, eclipse

according to the documentation of Android installation , I opened my Android SDK manager from tools folder of android_sdk_linux using terminal prompt ./android sdk . I then installed all of the necessary files listed under Android 4.1.2 . However , when I opened the Android SDK manager with in Eclipse , I see that those files were not installed . I try to install from those files again  under Android 4.1.2 , there is no warning from the eclipse editor , and it downloads normally . Is there any way to tell my SDK manager of Eclipse that I have already installed all of the necessary files .

I am using Eclipse Juno .

Edit: It turns out that I have download the core sdk files twice . The problem may fix if I can edit the android sdk path at the top , is it possible , and if so how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible to change the location of the SDK on Eclipse Juno (or any other version for that matter). Simply go to Window -> Preferences -> Android, and there you can put the path where your SDK has been installed.

[image]

HTH